# Accessing pair of row elements in array in Julia

Tags: julia

Suppose I have a following Array

```
A = [1 2; 1 3; 1 5; 2 1; 2 3; 2 4; 3 1; 3 3; 3 4; 3 1; 4 2; 4 3; 4 5; 5 2; 5 3; 5 5]
```

What is one liner in Julia to find if a pair of row elements exist in given array A. For example, one liner must return false for [1 4] as [1 4] row does not exist in A, and return true for [3 4]. I gave it a try in following manner where

```
[3 4] .== A
```

returns

```
0  1

1  0

1  0

1  1

1  0
```

whereas I want my output to be only "true" for

```
1 1
```

Comment: Note that Julia stores arrays in column major order (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order) so whatever algorithm you end up with will likely be much more efficient if you transpose the array and keep each pair of numbers as columns instead of rows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`eachrow`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.eachrow) allows iterating on the rows of a matrix, which you can simply combine with [`in`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.in), which checks whether an element is in a collection:

```
julia> A = [1 2; 1 3; 1 5; 2 1; 2 3; 2 4; 3 1; 3 3; 3 4; 3 1; 4 2; 4 3; 4 5; 5 2; ];

julia> [1, 4] in eachrow(A)
false

julia> [3, 4] in eachrow(A)
true
```

---

Another solution, more in line with your initial attempt would be something along the lines of:

```
julia> Ref([3, 4]) .== eachrow(A)
16-element BitArray{1}:
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 1
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0

julia> any(Ref([3,4]) .== eachrow(A))
true
```